# How to integrate lite-youtube in tinymce?

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-plugins

I'm trying to integrate the well-known lite-youtube plugin for writing tinymce's rich text.

And I did not succeed in understanding how to integrate the plugin into the system of tinymce, I would appreciate it if someone could help me with this, thanks

This is my code:

```
<script>
tinymce.init({
selector: '#myTextarea',
plugins: 'anchor autolink charmap codesample emoticons image link lists media searchreplace table visualblocks wordcount image',
toolbar: 'undo redo | blocks fontfamily fontsize | bold italic underline strikethrough | link image media table | align lineheight | numlist bullist indent outdent | emoticons charmap | removeformat | image | media',
language: 'he_IL',
image_class_list: [{title: 'Full size', value: 'great_picture_of_the_article'}],
image_dimensions: false,
link_class_list: [{title: 'Formatted link', value: 'link_to_external_site'}],
</script>
```

Here are the codes I tried to attach:

```
  media_url_resolver: function (data, resolve) {
    if (data.url.indexOf('YOUR_SPECIAL_VIDEO_URL') !== -1) {
      var embedHtml = '<lite-youtube videoid=' + data.url +
      '"></lite-youtube>';
      resolve({html: embedHtml});
    } else {
      resolve({html: ''});
    }
  },
video_template_callback: function(data) {
   return '<lite-youtube videoid="' + data.source1 + '"></lite-youtube>';
 },
```

Comment: updating:
This is the code that worked for me in the end
'extended_valid_elements: 'lite-youtube[videoid]',
custom_elements: 'lite-youtube','

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to use it at your tinymce.init(). It's work for me.

```
<script>
        tinymce.init({
        selector: '#myTextarea',
        plugins: 'anchor autolink charmap codesample emoticons image link lists media searchreplace table visualblocks wordcount image',
        toolbar: 'undo redo | blocks fontfamily fontsize | bold italic underline strikethrough | link image media table | align lineheight | numlist bullist indent outdent | emoticons charmap | removeformat | image | media',
        language: 'he_IL',
        image_class_list: [{title: 'Full size', value: 'great_picture_of_the_article'}],
        image_dimensions: false,
        extended_valid_elements: ['lite-youtube[videoid]'],
        link_class_list: [{title: 'Formatted link', value: 'link_to_external_site'}],
</script>
```

And put video to your HTML like this

```
<lite-youtube videoid="guJLfqTFfIw"></lite-youtube>
```

Where videoid - ID of Youtube video (see youtube video URL).

Or you can put video as usually, but before display text make preg_replace_callback in php, for example, (my choice) like this:

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8E8MU11X0YI"></iframe>
```

preg_replace_callback and regular expression

```
        $description = preg_replace_callback(
            '/<iframe.*?src="(.*?)".*?<\/iframe>/i',
            function($matches) {
                $src = $matches[1];
                if (strpos($src, 'youtube.com') !== false) {
                    return '<lite-youtube videoid="' . $src . '"></lite-youtube>';
                }
                return '';
            },
            $description
        );
```

and on exit:

```
<lite-youtube videoid="8E8MU11X0YI"></lite-youtube>
```

This code need to paste in source code of TinyMCE

I hope I helped you

Comment: Can you give me some explanation or show how exactly I integrate it into my test?

Comment: Yeah, please see previous comment

Comment: I didn't understand after I put this code how exactly do I embed lite-youtube videos in the textarea?

Comment: Okay, now it works great, do you have any idea, but how can it be done that at the moment of embedding there will actually be a preview of this video that I'm embedding because without it you just see an empty line and you don't know what the code is really there, for example when editing an article with several embedded videos..?